# Power BI Grouping

Tags: powerbi, aggregation, group

| Location | Won | Lost |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Home | 3 | 4 |
| Home | 2 | 3 |
| Home | 5 | 4 |
| Home | 4 | 6 |
| Away | 3 | 4 |
| Away | 2 | 3 |
| Away | 5 | 4 |
| Away | 4 | 6 |

This is an example table that I have in Power BI. I am trying to create a new table, that **groups by Location, sums up the values of won and lost, and adds a third column that has the ratio of sum(won)/sum(lost) called Ratio**. So all in all, you have three columns: Location (either home or away), Wins (sum of wins), Lost (sum of lost), ratio (the result of dividing wins and lost, the previous two columns)

How can I write the formula I need in Power BI?

Answer (score 0):

There is a function for that called `SUMMARIZE`, see [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dax/summarize-function-dax)

May be like:

```
SUMMARIZE(your_table  
      , your_table[Location]  
      , "Total Won", SUM(your_table[Won])  
      , "Total Lost", SUM(your_table[Lost])   
      , "Ratio", SUM(your_table[Won]/your_table[Lost])
      )
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also create this using Power Query.

- Your existing table is produce by a query named `myTable`
- In Power BI Desktop, select `Queries => Transform"
- In the PQ UI, select `Home=>Advanced Editor` and paste the code below into the window that opens.

  - You may need to change the name in the second line from `myTable` to whatever that query is really named
- I use the `Table.Group` function to do the appropriate calculations on each grouped sub-table

***M Code***

```
let
    Source = myTable,

//Group by Location, then add the columns
    #"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(myTable, {"Location"}, {
        {"Wins", each List.Sum([Won]), type nullable number}, 
        {"Losses", each List.Sum([Lost]), type nullable number},
        {"Ratio", each List.Sum([Won])/List.Sum([Lost]), type number}
        })
in
    #"Grouped Rows"
```

***Results from your data above***
[image]